# DocumentRoot: '/var/www/html' or '/home/httpd'?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

I'm setting up a brand new RHEL/Apache installation.  Should the DocumentRoot (webpage files) be /var/www/html or /home/httpd.  I've noticed both directories and am unsure which is more appropriate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

/var/www/html is where stuff should go.  /home/httpd is a very legacy location that was a default in the apache 1.x days but most software, any RPM packages you install, etc. will presume that your webroot is under /var/www.  Also the default SELinux rules tag files under /var/www automatically by default which should make management simpler for you by not going against the grain.

Comment: Say I move /var/www to /www and bind mount /www in /var/www.  This should work just the same, correct?

Comment: Sure that would be fine but just be sure you know what you are getting out of doing that.  If you make a new filesystem and mount it under both /www and /var/www what does having the other directory name get you.  If /www and /var/www are on the same filesystem what does fiddling with bind mounts and having another name get you?  If you make a new filesystem you can just mount it under /var/www and not overcomplicate it.

Comment: I only figured I would have a clearer view of where things are located from the root.  (Not to mention _slightly_ shorter paths.)  Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 3):

The main difference will be how your disks are partitioned.

- If you want a /home partition that's, say, on a RAID or is backed-up regularly, you may want to put your website's data on that partition.
- If your /var is on a RAID or being backed-up regularly, independently from /home, then maybe you want your website's data on /var instead, especially if you have other vital services that have their data sit on /var (like bind, postfix, cyrus, databases, etc.).
- If you don't backup anything and just have /home and /var on separate partitions, it's a matter of keeping user data separate (/home) from system data (/var).
- If you have both /home and /var on the same partition, then it doesn't really matter.

Comment: I would suggest using LVM to manage the volume creation and create a new volume any time you have a major application using space, otherwise if you have a large /home as you describe, use bind mounts rather than symlinks, as there are a few corner cases where they work better.  The distinction between user/system data is blurred as many applications store their data in /var such as databases, mail servers, web servers, etc.  Gratuitously changing these defaults tends to cause unforeseen problems later.

Comment: this makes sense.  Since I am running on a single partition, I'll just stick the standard like Jon Lin specified.

Answer (score 0):

Both paths are good options but not mandatory.

The de facto standard is /var/www for the server and /home/users* if userdir_mod is enabled.

But I don't use its, allow me to explain :)

The [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html) describe:

- **/var** contains variable data files. This includes spool directories
  and files, administrative and logging data, and transient and
  temporary files.
- **/home** is a fairly standard concept, but it is clearly a site-specific
  filesystem. The setup will differ from host to host. Therefore, no
  program should rely on this location.
- **/srv** contains site-specific data which is served by this system.

I leave /var/www for the default VirtualHost, with a fantastic It works! page or a redirection.

And the other VirtualHost DocumentRoot points to

```
 /srv/nameserver/cli/customernumber/domain/www80
```

Generaly /srv/nameserver/cli/customernumber is the mount point of a hard disk partition owned by the customer, local or NFS, and if the customer don't need to execute cgi's, I mount with noexec options in the fstab, i.e.:

```
LABEL=c128 /srv/cli/c128 ext4 rw,noexec,nosuid 0 2
```